# Really weird and disturbing things in my /boot/grub/grubenv file ..... Malware/Adware?

Tags: boot, grub2, malware

Since the last ubuntu (16.04) update, a few days ago, I have problems with grub. The grub-pc update didn't go well...  Now, at boot, it says: "Error: Invalid Environment Block. Press key to continue..." 
It is not a huge problem since it boots normally after that. But...
Looking at how to fix that, I found this:  https://learn.yancyparedes.net/2014/12/fixing-invalid-environment-block-of-grub/

Before I apply the solution above (and because I'm curious), I had a look at the /boot/grub/grubenv (binary file) And this is what I found:
(obtained with `more /boot/grub/grubenv`)

```
\E2\DA\DEh\00\BB\DA\DEfile:patterns.inieO\00\F0i{"content":["# Adblock Plus preferences","version=4","","[Subscription]","url=https://easylist-downloads.a  Z0plus.org/exce<\E8rules.txt","title=Allow non-intrusive advertising","fixedTi-8true","homepage\83ac`Pableads.com/","lastDo \934=1490883696","\A9PStatus=synchronize_ok
:Success69\00SCheck8942208","expire,10564esoftEation    171790=_\201703301411","requiredV-~2.-\AECount=6\00":\93\C0 filters]","! Text-based search ads on netzwelt.d!F$@@||google%2uds/$)\E50,subdocument,  main=rE\00cse?$\A6>\00! !\83ic image\A7t3n\A2uru!\D5(de/api/view\A7\00d \92^0\00u/b/$ZB*\00)%q0Sedo parking     Us",>!adsense/
!\F0\8D/caf.js$sitekey=MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBANnylWw2vLY4hUn9w06zQKbhKBfvjFUCsdFlb6TdQhxb9RXWXuI4t31c+o8fYOv/s8q1LGPga3DE1L/tHU4LENMCAwEAAQJ\AF\00(fs/gen_204?-\FE\AB\00\FE\AB\006\AB\00staticE|)S\00aA\82)\B0\FE\AA\00\FE\AA\002\AA\00img.sedoM"\B2\00^q*\FE\AF\00\FE\AF\00J\AF\00:\AB\00\00/\89u5\FE[\FE[=[ $elemhide\FE\95\00\FE\95\00.\95\00\||g.doubleclick.net/appsM\A5A\00/2\E3\FEQ\FEQ5Q\B5Ntext/E\9A\85\E24by 
InfluAds (h\ED\B6\00a:\A3forum\A5_@topic.php?t=9518)\8D\\00iD\A1\8Bco:\00","#@##!\00_W**
```

Indeed I have AdBlock Plus installed on my Chrome browser but it looks to me that it doesn't have anything to do here, or does'it?
Also there are references to apparently non-existing sites like Pableads.com and Z0plus.org which worry me... 
Am I the only one to have that in my grubenv file?

EDIT: After I applied the solution given in https://learn.yancyparedes.net/2014/12/fixing-invalid-environment-block-of-grub/ My PC boots normally. The problem is solved an my grubenv file is now like this:

```
# GRUB Environment Block

default=0
################################################################################
################################################################################
################################################################################
################################################################################
################################################################################
################################################################################
################################################################################
################################################################################
################################################################################
################################################################################
################################################################################
################################################################################
#############################
```

Best regards,
Stéphane

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Instead of editing the answer into your question, it would be much better to post it as an answer underneath your question.  That way, people will be able to see later that they can find an answer to the question without reading through your entire post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But, the problem/question is still about the posible malware?

I can't say how this crap ended in your `/boot/grub/grubenv` , but root access is required to edit this file!

Your can do some investigation to check you system against foreign modifications:

- look into your command line `history`, maybe a command caused this
- search the /var/log/* folder, especially `kern.log` and the `auth.log` for suspicious entries
- use [`rkhunter`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RKhunter)

  - `another rootkit detection software. Install the rkhunter package from the Universe Repository`
- use [`chkrootkit`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSecurityTools)

  - `chkrootkit can be used to help determine if a machine has been compromised. While not what you should use for the 'final word' on if you have been compromised, it runs a lot of useful checks and can direct suspicions towards finding a solution. To install chkrootkit install the chkrootkit package.`
- Verify files and packages agains the package manager:

  - `sudo debsums -a | grep -v OK`

Comment: Indeed, the question remains...  I use WINE because I need audio plugins which don't exist for linux. But! I must say that these plugins don't ask for admin permission. I would never had authorized it. (I'm Microsoftophobic!). They come from apparently trusted sources but I suspect it comes from one of them since the malware/adware doesn't seem to be well fitted with linux environnement (to prevent a computer from booting is not a paramount of discretion, is it?) 
The result of rkhunter --checkall
https://www.dropbox.com/s/in9cqi4q80jcpz7/rkhunter_result.txt?dl=0

Comment: And here is the result of "sudo chkrootkit": https://www.dropbox.com/s/qxiu9zcdzph4doa/chkrootkit.txt?dl=0

Comment: And here is the kern.log file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ymjssgsqe8mnxc/kern.log.txt?dl=0

Comment: Note: It looks like I'm not the first one having trouble after an grub related update: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1336942 (Have a look at the grubenv file link).

Comment: And here is the auth.log file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ptmp5jd3hjsh54l/auth.log.txt?dl=0

Comment: I looked at my history and yes...  there are weird things in it. Frome line 1 to 119: Binary looking lines referring to unwanted sites (for example: https://static.xx.fbcdn.net (which is weird since I left facebook a few years ago...) I'm not at complete ease with giving the auth.log file since I don't know what should stay confidential and what shouldn't...  But, from line 120 to 373, it looks again normal plain text commands which I know I issued myself.

Comment: Question: Couldn't this "history" command be used to detect automatically these frauds?

Comment: I would add a further a last comment to it: It looks like I got that crap by surfing on the web with my google-chrome (Version 58.0.3029.81 (64-bit)). I dont't know how, but there are references to my browsing history (for example to www.landr.com, www.pro-tool ans so on - which are perfectly legitimate sites). But also to session_sync related stuff (I don't known what it is...) or to https://mail.google.com/mail/u/... which is more worrying...

Comment: @S_Bersier why you added "ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair" "ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer" and other grub stuff on the 1. May?

Comment: @S_Bersier the history saves only used commands https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_(Unix)
to save the current condition, you can paste it into a new file with "history >history_backup.txt"

Comment: @S_Bersier it is strongly recommended to use a noscript addon on a web browser

Comment: I added boot-repair because of the failure of the grub-pc update. When grub-pcwas updated it opened a window asking me to check where I wanted to put my grub. I have 3 partitions.  The help says that when you don't know, you should check all of them, which I did. But, it said that it coundn't find "/." or something like that... (I don't remember exactly). I checked every possible combination of the three checkboxes unsuccessfully. So I continued, but installed boot-repair, just in case... When I rebooted the "Error: Invalid environnement... " showed up.

Comment: Do you have a recommandation about this noscript addon?

Comment: @S_Bersier I am not an expert in analysing these logs, but they I did not see anything explicit, if you can found something in the history, you should take a closer look at the commands

Comment: @S_Bersier I use firefox, not chrome with these plugins: https://pastebin.com/m5h71Vwk
Note: Shockwave Flash is deactivated by default

Comment: I can give you the line number 23 (for example) but I'm not sure it will help much... :-) :   https://www.dropbox.com/s/z8g88nxl0i66n1y/history_line_23.txt?dl=0

Comment: No, some weird stuff, bash would not exept this.  Maybe you pasted somthing accidentally to the terminal? ... but this would not explain the changes at grubenv. Any output here: `history | grep -i grubenv` ? (exept the command you used ;) )
If it is at line 23, it will be deleted soon. `history >history_backup.txt`

Comment: They are commands which I issued myself trying to the grub issue. Nothing suspicious there:  339  more grubenv
  340  sudo gedit grubenv 
  347  sudo cp grubenv grubenv.copy
  349  sudo rm grubenv
  350  sudo grub-editenv grubenv create
  351  more grubenv
  352  sudo grub-editenv grubenv set default=0
  353  grub-editenv grubenv list
  354  sudo grub-editenv grubenv list
  357  more grubenv
  358  more /boot/grub/grubenv
  361  sudo rm grubenv.copy 
  362  more /boot/grub/grubenv
  364  more /boot/grub/grubenv
  376  more /boot/grub/grubenv 
  377  history | grep -i grubenv

Comment: @S_Bersier ok, I am out of ideas right now